# Sorting a grouped report

Tags: sorting, ms-access, report, grouping

My schema looks a bit like this:

```
SEQ  GROUP1  GROUP2  GROUP3  VALUE
```

Where `SEQ` is roughly equivalent to the row number -- it's actually sort order, from an external table -- and the `GROUPx` fields delineate the data further. So, for example:

```
SEQ  GROUP1  GROUP2  GROUP3  VALUE
---- ------- ------- ------- ------
1    A       A       A       123
2    A       A       A       456
3    A       B       C       foo
5    X       Y       Z       bar
4    A       B       D       baz
```

I would like this data grouped in this hierarchy, but ordered by `SEQ`. So, the above data would produce a report like:

```
A
  A
    A
      123
      456
  B
    C
      foo
    D
      baz
X
  Y
    Z
      bar
```

I've been playing with the "grouping and sorting" options of the report and I seem to be able to have it ordered but not grouped, or grouped but not ordered!

For example, if I specify:

- Group by `GROUP1`

  - Group by `GROUP2`

    - Group by `GROUP3`

      - Order by `SEQ`

The values in the grouping level fields determine the order in which the data comes out. (In this case, the names I've chosen are in alphabetical order anyway, but if I changed the name of `X` in `GROUP1` to `123`, it would appear right at the top of the report.)

If I move the "Order by `SEQ`" to the highest priority, the order is correct, but the grouping levels are broken: Access basically treats the `SEQ` field as a grouping level and then the subsequent hierarchy is repeated for each value in that group.

Is there any way I can achieve what I'm looking for without having a `SEQx` field for each `GROUPx` field (rather than my current "global" `SEQ`)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to do a Left Join on this.  First, create a query using only SEQ, and order it by SEQ.  Then take your group-by query and Left Join it to your first query, so that it keeps the proper order.  Make sense?

Your query's code should more or less be:

```
SELECT 
First(B.SEQ) AS FirstOfSEQ, tblTest.Group1, tblTest.Group2, tblTest.Group3, tblTest.Val AS Val2 FROM (SELECT tblTest.SEQ FROM tblTest ORDER BY tblTest.SEQ) AS B 
LEFT JOIN tblTest ON B.SEQ = tblTest.SEQ 
GROUP BY tblTest.Group1, tblTest.Group2, tblTest.Group3, tblTest.Val 
ORDER BY First(B.SEQ);
```

In a report layout, order it by SEQ, then group it by the other values and you should get what you need.

Comment: n.b., "Group by" in an Access report is not the same thing as a SQL `GROUP BY` clause. It's a poor choice of words on Microsoft's part; maybe "Arrange by" or "Head by" would be better...

Comment: ...My point being that your solution isn't relevant. However, it is appreciated, so thank you :)

Comment: This absolutely did work for me:

SELECT First(B.SEQ) AS FirstOfSEQ, tblTest.Group1, tblTest.Group2, tblTest.Group3, tblTest.Val AS Val2
FROM (SELECT tblTest.SEQ
FROM tblTest
ORDER BY tblTest.SEQ)  AS B LEFT JOIN tblTest ON B.SEQ = tblTest.SEQ
GROUP BY tblTest.Group1, tblTest.Group2, tblTest.Group3, tblTest.Val
ORDER BY First(B.SEQ);    In a report layout, order it by SEQ, then group it by the other values and you should get what you need.

Comment: In which case, you might want to edit your original answer with this code, as it's not at all obvious that this is what you're suggesting... I'll try it with my data and get back to you.

Comment: Oops!  Sorry for the mix-up.  I edited the original answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this on my own

Select TimeOffRequestID, yourname AS "Employee Name", Replace(forwardcallsto, 'Select One', 'Voicemail') AS "Forward Calls To", appointment AS "Comments" FROM dbo.nei_TimeOffRequest
WHERE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),101) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN startingon AND endingon
ORDER BY yourname ASC